# access property of child directives

Tags: angular

Is it possible to access properties of child directives ?

Here in this example:

```
<parent>
   <child [name] = "foo"></child>
   <child [name] = "bar"></child>
</parent>
```

in `ParentComponent`, I would like to recuperate value `['foo','bar']`, that is the value and order of the propety name of `parent`'s child directives.

Is that possible ?

Comment: It's not really clear what's your case, but if you want to have both this array and these directives, it makes sense to generate the directives from the array, not in the opposite way.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm trying to acheive what I described here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45091905/mix-together-the-output-of-a-series-of-components   When you use primeng datables, you are using the properties of the child directives to build the parent directive. Any idea how that is possible ?